# How to format dataset with value labels to allow recoding of variables in another dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset which needs to be recoded using labels in another dataset. Recoding works when I create the labels dataframe in R ,but not when I read the same data from a csv file.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  gender=c(1,2,1,2),
  condition=c(1,1,2,2)
)
```

Codes created in R (using this works):

```
codes <- data.frame(
  gender_values= c("1", "2"),
  gender_labels= c("male gender","female gender"),
  condition_values = c("1", "2"),
  condition_labels = c("exp condition 1", "exp condition 2")
)
```

This works:

```
df$gender <- dplyr::recode(df$gender, !!!codes$gender_labels, .default = "nothing")
> df
         gender condition
1   male gender         1
2 female gender         1
3   male gender         2
4 female gender         2
```

Using the csv codes, the code does not work:

```
> dput(codes_csv)
structure(list(gender_values = "\"1\",\"2\"", gender_labels = "\"male gender\", \"female gender\"", 
    condition_values = "\"1\",\"2\"", condition_labels = "\"exp condition 1\", \"exp condition 2\""), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

df$gender <- dplyr::recode(df$gender, !!!codes_csv$gender_labels, .default = "nothing")

> df
                          gender condition
1 "male gender", "female gender"         1
2                        nothing         1
3 "male gender", "female gender"         2
4                        nothing         2
```

How could I format the cells in my csv file for the recode to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
codes_csv <- structure(list(gender_values = "\"1\",\"2\"", gender_labels = "\"male gender\", \"female gender\"", 
    condition_values = "\"1\",\"2\"", condition_labels = "\"exp condition 1\", \"exp condition 2\""), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))


codes_csv2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(codes_csv, function(x) 
      unlist(read.delim(textConnection(x), quote = "\"",sep = ",", 
      strip.white = T, header = F))))

codes_csv2
#>    gender_values gender_labels condition_values condition_labels
#> V1             1   male gender                1  exp condition 1
#> V2             2 female gender                2  exp condition 2
```

Comment: So basically we read each field as a table (read.delim) to take use of unquoting and delimiting capabilities. If you use regexps for the same purpose it could fail in rare situatons like labels with commas or quotes in the middle. Also manages data types.

Comment: This fails when I have a variable with an odd number of levels. I get the error message:  "arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 8, 2, 6". It does seem to work with even numbers. Any advice on how to customize this code when number of levels differ?

Comment: in your example all factors had the same number of levels so it is because of that you use a dataframe named "codes" (as dataframes columns must have the same number of elements). Thus, remove the "as.data.frame()" part of the code and it should work (but you of course will have not a df but a list)

Comment: Is there a way to have both a dataset and enough rows for all levels? I could think of initializing a dataset and filling it, but that seems involved. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: A priori no it isn't unless you want to deal with NA. But I insist: it is not necessary. Moreover, your dplyr::recode is exactly the same with lists than with data frame: you access the elements with codes$gender_labels and so.